# Error with installing chatterbot on Python

Tags: python, chatterbot

Whenever I try to install ChatterBot using `pip install ChatterBot` it always gives an error on this part:
`Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1 Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB) Installing build dependencies ... error`

I have tried reinstalling python multiple times but it doesn't seem to help any.
I have also tried to download spacy separately but it would just give the same errors

I am using Windows 10, Python version 3.8.5 with pip version 20.2.4.

```
Here's the error that I got from my log file:
2020-10-19T21:14:01,121     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.misc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,121     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bugfix' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,123     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.doc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,124     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.feature' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,125     warning: no previously-included files matching '*.removal' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,126     warning: no previously-included files matching 'NEWS' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,127     warning: no previously-included files matching 'README' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,128     warning: no previously-included files matching 'newsfragments' found under directory 'src\twisted'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,128     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\CREDITS'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,129     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\ChangeLog.Old'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,191     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pyproject.toml'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,192     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,193     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,193     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveralls.yml'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,194     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.circleci'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,195     warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.circleci'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,195     no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,196     no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,196     no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
2020-10-19T21:14:01,197     no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
2020-10-19T21:14:04,766     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
2020-10-19T21:14:04,767     warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\historic\2003'
2020-10-19T21:14:04,856     writing manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
2020-10-19T21:14:04,913     copying src\twisted\python\twisted-completion.zsh -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python
2020-10-19T21:14:04,915     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
2020-10-19T21:14:04,915     copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\common.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
2020-10-19T21:14:04,915     copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\index.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
2020-10-19T21:14:04,916     copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\summary.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
2020-10-19T21:14:04,917     copying src\twisted\test\cert.pem.no_trailing_newline -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,919     copying src\twisted\test\key.pem.no_trailing_newline -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,921     copying src\twisted\test\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,922     copying src\twisted\test\test_defer.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,922     copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\notes.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
2020-10-19T21:14:04,923     copying src\twisted\internet\test\_awaittests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,925     copying src\twisted\internet\test\_yieldfromtests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,925     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,925     copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,927     copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,928     copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,929     copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,930     copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
2020-10-19T21:14:04,931     copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\mail\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,932     copying src\twisted\python\test\_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,934     copying src\twisted\trial\test\_assertiontests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\trial\test
2020-10-19T21:14:04,935     copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\im
2020-10-19T21:14:04,937     copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\xish
2020-10-19T21:14:04,959     running build_ext
2020-10-19T21:14:04,960     building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
2020-10-19T21:14:07,878     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
2020-10-19T21:14:07,878     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
2020-10-19T21:14:07,878     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
2020-10-19T21:14:07,879     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted
2020-10-19T21:14:07,879     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\test
2020-10-19T21:14:07,879     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
2020-10-19T21:14:07,923     raiser.c
2020-10-19T21:14:08,005     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib
2020-10-19T21:14:08,115        Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.exp
2020-10-19T21:14:08,124     Generating code
2020-10-19T21:14:08,232     Finished generating code
2020-10-19T21:14:08,340     building 'twisted.internet.iocpreactor.iocpsupport' extension
2020-10-19T21:14:08,340     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet
2020-10-19T21:14:08,341     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
2020-10-19T21:14:08,341     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
2020-10-19T21:14:08,341     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.obj
2020-10-19T21:14:08,394     iocpsupport.c
2020-10-19T21:14:08,689     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2229): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
2020-10-19T21:14:08,690     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
2020-10-19T21:14:08,690     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 2
2020-10-19T21:14:08,690     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
2020-10-19T21:14:08,690     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2492): warning C4022: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
2020-10-19T21:14:08,692     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2838): warning C4022: 'PostQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
2020-10-19T21:14:08,692     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2949): warning C4022: 'CloseHandle': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
2020-10-19T21:14:08,693     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(3292): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,698     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(4932): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,698     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5149): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,700     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,701     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,702     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,702     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6182): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,703     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
2020-10-19T21:14:08,707     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
2020-10-19T21:14:08,707     c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
2020-10-19T21:14:08,709     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
2020-10-19T21:14:08,709     src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
2020-10-19T21:14:08,738     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
2020-10-19T21:14:08,765 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-ecgzh6t8\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-ecgzh6t8\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Windows\Temp\pip-record-3p44nc3g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 Exception information:
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 838, in install
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     success = install_legacy(
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 86, in install
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     raise LegacyInstallFailure
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 pip._internal.operations.install.legacy.LegacyInstallFailure
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 228, in _main
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     status = self.run(options, args)
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     return func(self, options, args)
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 397, in run
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     installed = install_given_reqs(
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 82, in install_given_reqs
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     requirement.install(
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 856, in install
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     six.reraise(*exc.parent)
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     raise value
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 74, in install
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     runner(
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 273, in runner
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     call_subprocess(
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766     raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
2020-10-19T21:14:08,766 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-ecgzh6t8\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-ecgzh6t8\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Windows\Temp\pip-record-3p44nc3g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
2020-10-19T21:14:08,789 Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-tjmgrbux'
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me

Comment: Try it with Python 3.7, the `tp_print` method was removed from the API in Python 3.8, and it looks like twisted hasn't fixed the issue yet. I'm having a similar issue when installing the `channels` pypy package in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 3):

I only got success by downgrading to chatterbot 1.0.4

```
1. pip install -U setuptools pip wheel
2. pip install -U chatterbot==1.0.4
```

I am using Windows 10, python 3.8.7 - 64 bit , pip 21.0.1,

Note: use 64 bit python, spacy will not install/work on 32bit python.